# How to Change Button Foreground Color Conditionally in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a button inside `ItemsControl` (pagination kind control) I have a property named `current_page` in my view model.

I want to compare `current_page` value to `Content` of `Button` that is (1 / 2 / 3) and want to change the foreground color of a button.

Please have a look at the code.

My ViewModel

```
public PaginationModel pagination
{
  get { return _pagination; }
  set { _pagination = value; OnPropertyChanged("pagination"); }
}
```

My Pagination Model

```
public class PaginationModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {
  private int _total_items;
  public int total_items {
    get {
      return _total_items;
    }
    set {
      _total_items = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("total_items");
    }
  }

  private int _items_per_page;
  public int items_per_page {
    get {
      return _items_per_page;
    }
    set {
      _items_per_page = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("items_per_page");
    }
  }

  private int _current_page;
  public int current_page {
    get {
      return _current_page;
    }
    set {
      if (value <= total_pages + 1 && value > 0) {
        _current_page = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("current_page");
      }
    }
  }

  private int _total_pages;
  public int total_pages {
    get {
      return _total_pages;
    }
    set {
      _total_pages = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("total_pages");
    }
  }

  private ObservableCollection < string > _PageList;

  public ObservableCollection < string > PageList {
    get {
      _PageList = new ObservableCollection < string > ();
      for (int i = 0; i < total_pages; i++) {
        _PageList.Add((i + 1).ToString());
      }
      return _PageList;
    }
    set {
      _PageList = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("PageList");
    }
  }
}
```

My Layout

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding pagination.PageList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                <Button Content="{Binding}"  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                             Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                                             Width="20"
                                             Margin="10,0"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Button Style Template

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WordOrangeBrush}"  />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource HelveticaNeue}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ff9f00"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ff9f00" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
        <!--I want to bind current page value in place of 1-->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Since the trigger is not working triggering on properties of `Button`, the `DataTrigger` shouldn't be part of the button's `ControlTemplate`, which is an "internal" control context, independent of any data type. Since the trigger triggers on properties of the current button's `DataContext`, the `DataTrigger` must be outside the `Button`, where it can access the `DataContext` like in a `Style` targeting `Button` or maybe even better in the `DataTemplate` of the item template. Here you are in a context that is specialized on the specific `DataContext` i.e. data type.

Comment: You could make that a listbox rather than itemscontrol Bind Foreground to a property of   selecteditem. Make PageList a list of viewmodels rather than just string. Add a brush property to that. Or use a converter to translate the number to a brush. With a fallbackvalue of WordOrangeBush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A Value Converter Solution

You cannot bind the `Value` of a `DataTrigger` to a property, because it is not a dependency property. You can work around this by creating a custom multi-value converter that checks pages for equality.

```
public class PageEqualityToBooleanConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return (int)values[0] == System.Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

The first value passed to the converter is the current page as `int` and the second value is the page on the `Button` as `string`. It is a bit odd that your `current_page` is of type `int`, but the `PageList` is a collection of type `string`, that is why we need to convert the second value.

Create an instance of the converter in your resources **before** your style, so you can reference it.

```
<local:PageEqualityToBooleanConverter x:Key="PageEqualityToBooleanConverter"/>
```

Finally, replace your `DataTrigger` with the one below. We are using a `MultiBinding` to be able to bind more than one value. The converter will convert both values to `True`, if the page values match, otherwise `False`.

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
   <DataTrigger.Binding>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PageEqualityToBooleanConverter}">
         <Binding Path="DataContext.pagination.current_page" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}"/>
         <Binding/>
      </MultiBinding>
   </DataTrigger.Binding>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

The first binding will find the parent `ItemsControl` to access the view model that contains the `current_page`. The second binding will bind to the data context of the associated button, which is the page string. If you change the `PageList` item type to `int` this will still work.

### Recommendations

I want to point out some observations on your code that might help you to improve it.

- As I already mentioned, it seems odd that your collection item type differs from your current item property type. Consider making it `int` or creating a separate page item view model if you plan on having other properties than the page number in it.
- You are defining an implicit style for `Button`, which gets applied to all `Button` controls in scope. If you use it in your pagination control only this *might* be ok, but if you intend to use it in other places, the `DataTrigger` should not be included in it, as it is specific to this data context only. Create separate style based on this one. Consider @BionicCode's comment about this.
- As @Andy pointed out in the comments, a [`ListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listbox?view=netcore-3.1) could be a better fit for a paginator, because it has the notion of a `SelectedItem` (and `IsSelected` properties on its item containers that can be bound in a `DataTrigger`), which is what you are trying to do here manually.

Answer (score 1):

The `Value` property of a `DataTrigger` cannot be data-bound.

What you should do is to create a type that represents a `Page`, add a `Number` and `IsCurrentPage` property to it and change the type of `PageList` to be an `ObservableCollection<Page>` instead of an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

You could then simply look up the corresponding `Page` in the `PageList` and set its `IsCurrentPage` property from the view model whenever the `current_page` property is set.

You should also make sure that the getter of the `PageList` property doesn't create a new collection each time it's invoked.